# Image growth on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make an image grow to 120% its current size on mouseover using jQuery? Also, when the mouse moves off the image, it should return to its original size.

```
$("img").mouseover(function (){
              ???
});
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? You can solve it with a simple `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

```
div{width:50%;margin:30px auto;height:300px;transition:1s;}
div:hover{transform:scale(1.2);}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/Bovvjg

That is all you need, there is no need to use jQuery for this, it takes way more code, vanilla JS is too much code as well for this effect, you will need mouseover and mouseout events and add/remove classes.
Let me know if you want it in JS or Jquery, and I will add it to the code there.

Comment: Just say if you want the native JS code as well. But I would never really use JS for hover effects, it is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

As answered above, you don't need jQuery for this. You can handle it with pure CSS. But I wrote a sample with jQuery for you:

```
$(function(){
    $("img").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({
            "transform" : "scale(1.2)",
            "transition" : "1s"
        })}, function(){
            $(this).css({
            "transform" : "scale(1.0)",
            "transition" : "0.5s"
        });
    });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("img").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({
            "transform" : "scale(1.2)",
            "transition" : "1s"
        })}, function(){
          $(this).css({
            "transform" : "scale(1.0)",
            "transition" : "0.5s"
  });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://orig11.deviantart.net/ad48/f/2012/198/1/4/above_the_clouds_by_bluesixtynine-d57jb7b.jpg" width="50%" />
```